# Parallel random Forest missing MSE and R-squared

Tags: r

I run a non-parallel randomForest object with no problem like this:

```
> rf <- randomForest(t2[,-c(1,2,7,12)],t2[,2],
+                    ,sampsize=c(10000),do.trace=F,importance=TRUE,ntree=1,,forest=TRUE)
Warning message:
In randomForest.default(t2[, -c(1, 2, 7, 12)], t2[, 2], , sampsize = c(10000),  :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
> rf

Call:
 randomForest(x = t2[, -c(1, 2, 7, 12)], y = t2[, 2], ntree = 1,      sampsize = c(10000), importance = TRUE, do.trace = F, forest = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 1
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.07444926
                    % Var explained: -19.36
> rf$rsq
[1] -0.1936248
```

Now I run the same code using parallel stuff and get no MSE or % Var Explained:

```
> library("foreach")
> library("doSNOW")
> registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(2, type="SOCK"))
> 
> 
> 
> rf <- foreach(ntree = rep(1, 2), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar%
+ randomForest(t2[,-c(1,2,7,12)],t2[,2],
+                    ,sampsize=c(10000),do.trace=F,importance=TRUE,ntree=1,,forest=TRUE)
> rf

Call:
 randomForest(x = t2[, -c(1, 2, 7, 12)], y = t2[, 2], ntree = 1,      sampsize = c(10000), importance = TRUE, do.trace = F, forest = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 2
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

> rf$rsq
NULL
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not the parallel bits, its the use of `combine` from the randomForest package. Quoting `?combine`:

> The confusion, err.rate, mse and rsq components (as well as the
>   corresponding components in the test compnent, if exist) of the
>   combined object will be NULL.

So you'll have to calculate that stuff yourself using the predicted values.