# Calculate R-squared (%Var explained) from combined randomForest regression object

Tags: r, random-forest

When calculating a `randomForest` regression, the object includes the R-squared as "`% Var explained: ...`".

```
library(randomForest)
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(ggplot2::diamonds[1:1000,1:7])
rf <- randomForest(formula = carat ~ ., data = dat, ntree = 500)
rf
# Call:
#   randomForest(formula = carat ~ ., data = dat, ntree = 500) 
#                Type of random forest: regression
#                      Number of trees: 500
# No. of variables tried at each split: 2
# 
# Mean of squared residuals: 0.001820046
# % Var explained: 95.22
```

However, when using a `foreach` loop to calculate and `combine` multiple `randomForest` objects, the R-squared values are not available, as it is noted in `?combine`:

> The `confusion`, `err.rate`, `mse` and `rsq` components (as well as the corresponding components in the test compnent, if exist) of the combined object will be `NULL`

```
cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

rfPar <- foreach(ntree=rep(63,8), 
                 .combine = combine, 
                 .multicombine = T, 
                 .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% 
                 {
                   randomForest(formula = carat ~ ., data = dat, ntree = ntree)
                 }
stopCluster(cl)

rfPar
# Call:
#   randomForest(formula = carat ~ ., data = dat, ntree = ntree) 
#                Type of random forest: regression
#                      Number of trees: 504
# No. of variables tried at each split: 2
```

Since it was not really answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7880422/3250126): Is it at all possible to calculate the R-squared (% Var explained) and Mean of squared residuals from an `randomForest` object afterwards?

(Critics of this parallelization might argue to use `caret::train(... method = "parRF")`, or others. However, this turns out to take forever. In fact, this might be useful for anybody who uses `combine` to merge `randomForest` objects...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  You can calculate the R-squared value after the fact by taking the predictions that result from your training data and your trained model and comparing them to the actual values:

```
# taking the object from the question:
actual <- dat$carat
predicted <- unname(predict(rfPar, dat))

R2 <- 1 - (sum((actual-predicted)^2)/sum((actual-mean(actual))^2))
```

Or Mean Squared Error:

```
caret::RMSE(predicted,actual)
```

Comment: One-liner for the pseudo-R2: `R2 <- 1 - var(rfPar$y - rfPar$predicted) / var(rfPar$y)`